# Understanding how to resolve reduce/reduce & shift/reduce conflicts

Tags: c, bison, yacc

I have the following tokens, operator precedence and grammar rules in my parser.y file:

```
%token <intval> INTCONST
%token <realval> REALCONST
%token <strval> STRCONST
%token <strval> IF ELSE WHILE FOR FUNCTION RETURN BREAK CONTINUE
%token <strval> AND NOT OR LOCAL TRUE FALSE NIL ID
%token <strval> PAR_L PAR_R BRACK_L BRACK_R DOT DOTDOT PLUS PLUSPLUS MIN MINMIN
%token <strval> MUL DIV MOD GRTR GRTREQ LESS LESSEQ ASSIGN EQUAL NEQUAL
%token <strval> CBRACK_L CBRACK_R SEMICOL COMMA COL COLCOL

%left PAR_L PAR_R
%left BRACK_L BRACK_R
%left DOT DOTDOT
%right NOT PLUSPLUS MIN MINMIN
%left MUL DIV MOD
%left PLUS
%nonassoc GRTR GRTREQ LESS LESSEQ
%nonassoc EQUAL NEQUAL
%left AND OR
%right ASSIGN


%start program
/*ALPHA GRAMMAR*/
%%   
program:                        stmtlist            
                            ;
stmtlist:                        stmtlist stmt      
                            |
                            ;
stmt:                           expr SEMICOL        
                                                    
                                                    
                            |   ifstmt
                            |   whilestmt
                            |   forstmt
                            |   returnstmt
                            |   BREAK SEMICOL
                            |   CONTINUE SEMICOL
                            |   block
                            |   funcdef
                            |   SEMICOL
                            ;
expr:                           assignexpr
                            |   expr op expr
                            |   term
                            ;
op:                             PLUS | MIN | MUL | DIV | MOD | GRTR | GRTREQ | LESS | LESSEQ | EQUAL | NEQUAL | AND | OR
                            ;
term:                           PAR_L expr PAR_R
                            |   MIN expr
                            |   NOT expr
                            |   PLUSPLUS lvalue
                            |   lvalue PLUSPLUS
                            |   MINMIN lvalue
                            |   lvalue MINMIN
                            |   primary
                            ;
assignexpr:                     lvalue ASSIGN expr
                            ;
primary:                        lvalue
                            |   call
                            |   objectdef
                            |   PAR_L funcdef PAR_R
                            |   const
                            ;
lvalue:                         ID
                            |   LOCAL ID
                            |   DOTDOT ID
                            |   member
                            ;
member:                         lvalue DOT ID
                            |   lvalue BRACK_L expr BRACK_R
                            |   call DOT ID
                            |   call BRACK_L expr BRACK_R
                            ;
call:                           call PAR_L elist PAR_R
                            |   lvalue callsuffix
                            |   PAR_L funcdef PAR_R PAR_L elist PAR_R
                            ;
callsuffix:                     normcall
                            |   methodcall
                            ;
normcall:                       PAR_L elist PAR_R
                            ;
methodcall:                     DOTDOT ID PAR_L elist PAR_R // equivalent to lvalue.id(lvalue, elist)
                            ;
elist:                          expr
                            |   elist COMMA expr
                            |
                            ;
objectdef:                      BRACK_L elist | indexed BRACK_R
                            ;
indexed:                        indexedelem
                            |   indexed COMMA indexedelem
                            |
                            ;
indexedelem:                    CBRACK_R expr COL expr CBRACK_R
                            ;
block:                          CBRACK_L stmtlist CBRACK_R
                            ;
funcdef:                        FUNCTION ID PAR_L idlist PAR_R block
                            ;
const:                          number | STRCONST | NIL | TRUE | FALSE
                            ;

number:                         INTCONST
                            |   REALCONST
                            ;

idlist:                         ID
                            |   idlist COMMA ID
                            |
                            ;
ifstmt:                         IF PAR_L expr PAR_R stmt ELSE stmt
                            ;
whilestmt:                      WHILE PAR_L expr PAR_R stmt
                            ;
forstmt:                        FOR PAR_L elist SEMICOL expr SEMICOL elist PAR_R stmt
                            ;
returnstmt:                     RETURN expr SEMICOL
                            ;
```

When running `bison -v --defines --output=parser.c parser.y`, I get around 58! shift/reduce conflicts and 10 reduce/reduce. In the output file, there are obviously multiple states where conflicts arise, but I'll only mention one so that I can work on all the others by myself. Let's look at state 21:

```
State 21 conflicts: 2 shift/reduce, 2 reduce/reduce

State 21

   62 objectdef: BRACK_L • elist

INTCONST   shift, and go to state 4
REALCONST  shift, and go to state 5
STRCONST   shift, and go to state 6
NOT        shift, and go to state 14
LOCAL      shift, and go to state 15
TRUE       shift, and go to state 16
FALSE      shift, and go to state 17
NIL        shift, and go to state 18
ID         shift, and go to state 19
PAR_L      shift, and go to state 20
BRACK_L    shift, and go to state 21
DOTDOT     shift, and go to state 22
PLUSPLUS   shift, and go to state 23
MIN        shift, and go to state 24
MINMIN     shift, and go to state 25
CBRACK_R   shift, and go to state 27

BRACK_R   reduce using rule 61 (elist)
BRACK_R   [reduce using rule 66 (indexed)]
MIN       [reduce using rule 61 (elist)]
CBRACK_R  [reduce using rule 61 (elist)]
COMMA     reduce using rule 61 (elist)
COMMA     [reduce using rule 66 (indexed)]
$default  reduce using rule 61 (elist)

expr         go to state 59
term         go to state 31
assignexpr   go to state 32
primary      go to state 33
lvalue       go to state 34
member       go to state 35
call         go to state 36
elist        go to state 60
objectdef    go to state 37
indexed      go to state 38
indexedelem  go to state 39
const        go to state 42
number       go to state 43
```

If I'm understanding things correctly, the parser has already seen the BRACK_L token and is now at the cursor (dot) location. If the next token that he sees is any of the following (BRACK_R, MIN, CBRACK_R, COMMA) he comes across a conflict (as noted by the []), correct?

I'm having a hard time recognizing where these conflicts are within the grammar rule(s) in question. For example, is the first reduce/reduce conflict caused due to the parser not knowing if it should use the `elist` or the `indexed` rule when faced with a `BRACK_R` token? Are the shift/reduce conflicts in question being caused by the `MIN` and `CBRACK_R` tokens here?

If the above is true, in the first reduce/reduce example mentioned above, where is the `BRACK_R` in the `indexed` or `elist` rule in order for them to be an issue?

Comment: Start small and simple! Don't write large parts of code in one go without building and testing. If you start with the most simple grammar possible, and add one simple rule at a time, you will know exactly when and where the conflicts happen, and might have a better chance to solve it.

Comment: What do you think `objectdef:  BRACK_L elist | indexed BRACK_R` means? I suspect you're reading it as though it meant `BRACK_L ( elist | indexed ) BRACK_R`, but you couldn't write that in yacc/bison because grouping parentheses aren't part of the grammar syntax. `|` is just an abbreviation for a new production with the same left-hand side.

Comment: There are other problems as well, particularly with the precedence declarations. You should review the documentation. You cannot hide the operators inside a non-terminal like `OP`.

Answer (score 0):

> If I'm understanding things correctly, the parser has already seen the
> BRACK_L token and is now at the cursor (dot) location. If the next
> token that he sees is any of the following (BRACK_R, MIN, CBRACK_R,
> COMMA) he comes across a conflict (as noted by the []), correct?

Exactly, the dot indicates the current state of the parser:

```
   62 objectdef: BRACK_L • elist
```

After that, you will see all the shift & reduce possibilities, along with the default action:

```
INTCONST   shift
...
CBRACK_R   shift

BRACK_R   reduce
...
COMMA     reduce
$default  reduce using rule 61
```

> If the above is true, in the first reduce/reduce example mentioned
> above, where is the BRACK_R in the indexed or elist rule in order for
> them to be an issue?

Yes, having uncertainties between whether to shift or reduce is bad, but having uncertainties between reduce rules is even worse, because Bison does not know if it should reduce to rule `61` or rule `66` in case BRACK_R arrives:

```
BRACK_R   reduce using rule 61 (elist)
BRACK_R   [reduce using rule 66 (indexed)]
```

You should rewrite your grammar taking into account that Bison can only read one token ahead of the current state. Beyond that, there is uncertainty. If you cannot improve your grammar, you may consider rewriting the tokens to reduce the uncertainty (for example, split BRACK_R in two different symbols).